# Matrix, cofactor, minor, Determinant proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, laplace-expansion

I'm looking at Apostol's Calculus and I found something that might be trivial but I can't see it directly.

$det A_{12}'=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & ...& 0\\
a_{21} & 0 & a_{23} & ...& a_{2n}\\
. & . & . & ...& .\\
. & . & . & ...&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&\\
a_{n1}&0&a_{n3}&...&a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}=detA_{12}\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & ...& 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & ...& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & ...& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1...& 0\\
.&.&.&.&.&\\
0&0&0&...&1
\end{vmatrix}
$

$detA_{12}'$ here is the cofactor and $A_{12}$ is the minor. It said the equation above is from uniqueness theorem. I can see this function satisfies Axiom 1-3, but I don't know why the $d(A_1,...,A_n)=detA_{12}$ and why $f(I)$ would be the right-hand side determinant of this non-identity matrix. Can anyone explain this? I'm not sure if I misunderstood some basic concepts here...

The uniqueness theorem I have is: Let $d$ and $f$ be functions satisfying AXIOMS 1-4 and 1-3 respectively. Then,
$f(A_1, . . . , A_n) = d(A_1, · · · , A_n)f(I_1, . . . , I_n).$
In particular, if $f$ satisfies, in addition, AXIOM 4, then $f = d$.

Besides, Apostol explained $J$ is the identity matrix of order $n-1$ but I don't know why $f(J)$ would look like the matrix below. I thought if it's identity matrix then $f(J)$ would be 1. Thank you for helping me clarify on this! I'm really confused.

> $f(J)$ is by definition of the detriment of the matrix:
> \begin{matrix}
> 0 & 1 & 0 & ...& 0\\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & ...& 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & ...& 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1...& 0\\
> .&.&.&.&.&\\
> 0&0&0&...&1
> \end{matrix}

Answer (score 1):

I haven't the book at hand and I don't know which pages or section you are referring to, but the idea is to view
$$
\det A_{12}'=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots& 0\\
a_{21} & 0 & a_{23} &\cdots& a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&0&a_{n3}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
as a function $f(B_1,B_3,\ldots,B_n)$ of the rows/columns (depending on the convention adopted by Apostol) of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix
$$
B=\,\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{23} &\cdots& a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n3}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It should be straightforward to verify that $f$ is an alternating multilinear function (i.e. a function satisfying the axioms you mentioned) of $B_1,B_3,\ldots,B_n$. It follows from the uniqueness theorem that
$$
f(B_1,B_3,\ldots,B_n)=d(B_1,B_3,\ldots,B_n)f(J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_{n-1}),
$$
where $J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_{n-1}$ are the rows/columns of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ identity matrix $J$. However, $d(B_1,B_3,\ldots,B_n)$ is precisely the minor $\det A_{12}$ and
$f(J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_{n-1})$ is precisely the RHS of $(1)$ when the $a_{ij}$s are replaced by the entries of $J$. Hence
$$
f(J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_{n-1})=
\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&1&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\ddots&0&1&\ddots&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&\cdots&0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: I get what you said about seeing it as a function of $(n-1) x (n-1)$. But I'm still a little confused why $f(J)$ would look like this. My question is if $J$ is the identity matrix, would $f(J)$ be 1? @user1551

Comment: @Kylinny No,$f$ is merely an alternating multilinear function. It is **not** the determinant function, i.e. $f(B)$ is not $\det(B)$. In fact, $f(J)=-1\ne1=\det(J)$.